# android studio gradle error app:processDebugResources

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been working on a project for a few weeks. When I tried to run the app today i ran into a problem. When i run the it fails and says

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Nir\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

it also says cant resolve symbol R, but i didn't change the code.

I tried to clean the project and sync with gradle, but nothing worked.

Please help me find the problem.

Comment: File -> Invalidate caches/restart - choose invalidate and restart

Comment: Please show more of the Gradle output. There's not enough information here to give an accurate answer other than tell you a resource file is corrupt / invalid

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once. It happened after I deleted some images from res/drawable, and than pressed cmd+z (undo last command). Images were corrupted.

So you may try to check your images. 
If it wont help, try to remove .gradle folder and rebuild the project.

Answer (score -3):

File->Project Structure->Build Tools Version->Change to 23.0.1